# Azure Active Directory OAuth authentication to on-prem IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have on-premise ASP.Net application and it is currently using windows authentication. Is it possible to implement Azure Active Directory OAuth authentication to on-prem IIS?

Answer (score 0):

I think external authentication is not depending of web server, you have to add it to your app. [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services).
I recommend to try [AAD B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/external-identities/b2c/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add AAD authentication at the application level, but for the IIS Web server level, this is not possible.

For your application, because it is an ASP.net application, you can easily integrate Azure AD authentication with it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory). However, for the IIS service level, Azure AD oAuth does not provide native support, so you cannot implement Azure Active Directory OAuth authentication on the local IIS.

Please check for [similar questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/11093/windows-iis-integration-with-azure-ad.html).

Comment: Hi, If you still have any doubts, I will answer you as soon as possible.